# Currency formatting Issues

Tags: java, currency

I am trying to convert an input string to euro/Bulgarian currency,I am having two scenario's.

First,
When input is 10,000 the Bulgarian format should be like 10 000 and euro format should be 10.000

Second,
if the input is 10.23 then both European and Bulgarian format should be 10,23.
I am trying to do using Big Decimal,Something like,

```
String s = "+000000055511.00";
         BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(s.replace(",", "."));
         b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
         System.out.println(b.toPlainString());
```

But I am not able to do it as an common utility which takes and converts into euro or bulgarian currency.Is there any utility for the same?Can somebody help me?

Comment: did you tried use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)` with appropriate locals. If there are no such locals which match your requirements then construct your own decimal formatter `java.text.DecimalFormat` with pattern `##' '##0.00` resp.  `##,##0.00` plus appropriate currency sign. The formatter can be applied to `BigDecimal`:

```
String s = "+000000027511.00";
BigDecimal B = new BigDecimal(s);
// don't replace "." by ",": english number format expected here
b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat(...); //initialize as requested see docs
System.out.println(f.format(b));
```

Another question is why you don't want fraction digits if your number is 10,000? If this is really the case you must define two formatters more and must select them according to your creteria.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: Oracle's Java 7 implementation [supports](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) `bg_BG` for `java.util` and `java.text`.